# Use partial templates to create a single instance of DOM element shared in ionic framework (angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, ionic-framework, partials

I want to use partial template to render a video element in my ionic app. I want that to be shared across all the templates.

For eg: Let's say I have a 'displayPage' template that renders a specific page with an id say 'x'. That would have a video element. Now when I show page id 'y', it would use the same 'displayPage' template to render the page with id 'y'. I want that to also have the video element. The video element is shared between these two pages and therefore I thought I'd use a partial template to include the video element.

I do something like (in `displayPage.html`:

```
<div class="video-background" ng-controller="ActivityCtrl">
      <ng-include src="'templates/videoPlayer.html'"></ng-include>  
</div>
```

`videoPlayer.html` looks like :

```
<video ng-if="item.video"
          id="vid1"
          class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
          poster={{videoThumbnail}}
          controls
          data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "{{trustSrc(item.Url)}}"}] }'>
 </video>
```

The item object is defined in the scope of `ActivityCtrl` that controls both these templates.

The `video` element however that is rendered is not one. So, basically it gets rendered as a child every time a page is loaded using UI routing. That is problematic because I am using [Video-js Youtube plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/) to play the videos and the event bindings happen the first time this template is loaded and scripts are initialized. So basically I end up with **n** `video` elements with id "vid1" if I render **n** pages. I want the `video` element to be created once and that be shared no matter which page is rendered.

That was my intention of using `ng-include`. Now, I am a beginner with AngularJS but I hope I was able to explain my problem. I want that one dom element only to be shared and not recreated on whenever a new page is shown and also I want the `ActivityCtrl` to be able to inject the `item` object into that shared `video` element that's created only once and therefore has the right event listeners binding.

Comment: The DOM doesn't work that way. When you remove the element to switch views it is removed from the dom...a new view creates new instance. you need to use a directive to do whatever it is you want with video element

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for your quick reply. Can you give me some idea on how to use a directive to solve this specific problem of preserving that DOM element and its event bindings?

Comment: Again...you are thinking about this wrong. Directive would work with each new instance. Might need to use `$destroy` to destroy whatever lbrary does if it has destroy methods